# How to configure Selenium Grid with NUnit3 parallel test execution?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver, nunit-3.0

Our current C#/Nunit 2.6.3 test framework has a regression suite that takes over 35 hours to run on a single pc,fixtures with some tests lasting as long as 20 minutes. Setting up batches of tests to run on multiple machines is time consuming and inefficient so I'm trying to migrate the tests to NUnit 3 to get the benefit of parallel execution on Selenium Grid.

It is my aim to have 12 nodes each running a single instances of IE. However it appears the NUnit3 Test adapter for VS is trying to run all tests simultaneously.

As I will always be executing tests from more fixtures than I will have nodes it is important that fixtures will sit in a queue until a node becomes available. In practice a test fixture may have to wait a couple of hours for a free node.
For my current configuration experiment I have the following set up:

- A hub with the following config:`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar -role hub -newSessionWaitTimeout:-1  -browserTimeout 120  -timeout 3600`
- A single node in default config.
- Two test fixtures, each with 10 tests. The test fixtures have the following attribute: `[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Self)]`

In this situation I would expect that as only a single node that is supporting a single instance of IE then only a single test would be executed. The hub would then send the next test in the queue to the node when it became free. However it appears that both test fixtures are being run simultaneously. One test is pushed to the node but tests on the other fixture are failing with the following message:

**Result Message:

OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session timed out after 60 seconds.
  ----> System.Net.WebException : The operation has timed out**

When I used grid on Eclipse in a Java/JUnit framework I had no problems. The hub would queue tests until a node became free without any timeout, using the default config.

Does anyone know the correct configuration or is this a problem with the NUnit 3 Test adapter? Browser choice is unfortunately fixed as IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that number of parallel threads can be controlled by setting the LevelOfParallelism Attribute in the AssemblyInfo.

```
//Determines the number parallel threads that run simultaneously
[assembly: LevelOfParallelism(7)]
```

If this attribute is set to the number of nodes available then the tests queue as I expected.